# how to handle files creating and zipping using php in linux and windows

Tags: php, linux, windows, rest

i've a problem with my code that i use to create a temporary folder where i store some qrcode png images then zip the whole folder then send it via json , locally it works perfectly , but in the production environment it doesn't work , my guess is that it's a problem realted to the fact that i'm using windows locally but the production env uses linux

```
            if (sizeof($tableNum) > 1) {

                // creating zip file

                $zip_file = './PngQrCodes.zip';

                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                if ($zip->open($zip_file, ZipArchive::CREATE) !== TRUE) {
                    exit(json_encode(array("STATUS" => "ERROR", "MSG" => "problem creating the zip file")));
                }
                // creating /images directory
                if (!file_exists($tmpdir)) {
                    mkdir($tmpdir, 0777, true);

                }

                /*$barcodeobj->getBarcodePNG(6, 6, array(0,0,0));*/
                foreach ($tableNum as $tablename) {


                    // generating Url
                    $code = "URL/table/" . $tablename['name'];

                    //generating Qrcode

                    $barcodeobj = new TCPDF2DBarcode($code, 'QRCODE,L');

                    $fileName = $tablename['name'] . '.png';
                    $path = 'Images/' . $fileName;
                    //transforming qrcode into png image and putting it into /Images directory

                    file_put_contents($path, $barcodeobj->getBarcodePngData(6, 6, array(0,0,0)));


                    //add png qrcode to zip file

                    $zip->addFile($path, $fileName);


                }

                // close zip file

                $zip->close();


                // deleting png qrcodes
                $files = glob('Images/*.*');
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    unlink($file);
                }

                // download zip file
                ob_clean();
                flush();
                readfile($zip_file);
                json_encode($zip_file);

                unlink($zip_file);

                



            }else {

                $code = "URL/table/" . $tableNum[0]['name'];
                $barcodeobj = new TCPDF2DBarcode($code, 'QRCODE,L');
                $barcodeobj->getBarcodePNG(6, 6, array(0,0,0));
```

Comment: *in the production environment it doesn't work* could do with some clarification as to what doesn't work.  Is the zip file on the server OK, is it the download that fails.

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't an error message, and it's not a useful description of your problem either. Try to describe the issue clearly and specifically.

Comment: yes the download fails , i'm using vuejs in the front end to download the zip file but i'm getting "the archive is either in unknown format or damaged error"

Comment: it works just fine locally , i can extract the images but it fails on the production env

Comment: Ignore Vue for now completely. Instead, visit the URL using a traditional browser and look for error messages. Check the server logs. Almost all file-related functions including `mkdir` and `file_get_contents` return a boolean on failure, check those. Make sure to set error handling to be very loud while debugging this.